# how to run a symfony and a non-symfony project on the same server

Tags: apache2.4, symfony5

I want to run different php project on my apache server : one is a symfony 5 project and other are classic php projects.
in my httpd-vhosts.conf apache configuration file, I put these parameters for running the symfony projet :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/em_occurence_v2/public"
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/em_occurence_v2/public">
         AllowOverride None
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from All
         FallbackResource /index.php
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this URL (for my symfony project) works fine : http://localhost/aff_date_prep_data

but my other non-symfony projet, like this URL, doesn't : http://localhost/em_occurence/em_occ.php

how can I configure my httpd-vhosts.conf file to add these others projects ?

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finaly find how to access to Symfony project without modifing any apache configuration file.

the name of the Symfony project is : "em_occurence_v2", so I could access to all symfony route (for example "aff_date_prep_data"), with this kind of URL :

http://localhost/em_occurence_v2/public/index.php/aff_date_prep_data

So I could access my old non-Symfony project with using this URL :

http://localhost/em_occurence/em_occ.php